# Python - File to dict

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm starting Python self study and trying systematize some manual processes that I do every day.
I'm using Python 2.7 and I have a file with this structure:

```
#description
  key 1
    key 2
      key n
        value 1
        value 2
      exit n
    exit 2
  exit 1
#description
```

The only pattern that exists is a tab at the beginning of the line.

The text is tabulated with 2 spaces (  ) at the begin and it can reach the depth of 6 tabs (12 spaces or key 6).
The name of the key (1..6) also varied and do not follow a pattern.

Sorry for my poor English if I could not make it clear.

I need the text in this file to turn a similar dictionary like this one:

```
{ 'key 1' : [{ 'key 2' : [{ 'key n' : ['value 1', 'value 2', 'exit n']}, 'exit 2']}, 'exit 1']}
```

I have read a lot about how to manipulate dictionaries, search here in StackOverflow but I have not yet been able to compose a code that does what I need.

Thanks and I apologize in advance if the doubt is very basic.

Comment: Would not you rather get this dictionnary: `{'1': {'2': {'n': [1, 2]}}}`? This would certainly be more useful.

Comment: Parsing files can be awkward when you're learning, why not use something that already exists like YAML?

Comment: Whats wrong with using something like JSON?

Comment: @SamMason, I formatted my text file with the YAML structure and work fine now.
Thank you for all by attention spended